# Python: How can I create a GoogleCredentials using a specific user instead of get_application_default()

Tags: python, gcloud, google-cloud-python, gcloud-python

I'm updating a script to call OAuth2-protected Google Cloud endpoints.  The previous version assumed a single user previously authenticated by `gcloud auth login` and thus was able to use the default:

```
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
```

However now I must do some calls as user A and some as user B.  I can perform these steps in the shell to generate access tokens, but I would prefer to do it in the program directly:

```
gcloud auth login user_A@email.com
gcloud auth print-access-token user_A@email.com
```

Is there a way to generate two `Credentials` values for two different emails without having to run any shell commands?

Answer (score 5):

My case is a bit different but hopefully, you can find the equivalent for your use case.
I'm using service accounts for authentication.

You need 3 things for successful authentication

1. Service account file. This is the JSON file you get after creating a service account
2. SCOPES. This specifies which Google API you need to access. In my case I needed to access the Google Groups API.
   Hence the scope I needed was: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group"

you can find the list of all scopes here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes

3. Email address of the required user. This is the email address of the user your service account wants to impersonate (user_A@email.com). In my case I needed the G suite admin's email, as they only have access to Google Groups.

Following is the equivalent Python code:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group"]
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = "my-service-account.json"

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
        SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,
        scopes=SCOPES,
        subject="admin@example.com")

admin_service = build("admin", "directory_v1", credentials=credentials)
group = admin_service.groups().list(domain="example.com").execute()
print("groups list: ", group)
```

Now according to your question if you want to impersonate some other user. Then you can use

```
new_user_email = "user2@example.com"
user2_credentials = credentials.with_subject(new_user_email)
new_service = build("admin", "directory_v1", credentials=user2_credentials)
# use this new_service to call required APIs
```

Here is the link to the docs for  authentication using service accounts for python library: https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html

Here is the link of how the Oauth flow happens in general for service accounts: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/oauth-server.md

I hope this was of some help to you.

PS - This is my first answer on Stack Overflow, so please do tell me how I could've improved my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use

```
gcloud auth application-default login
gcloud auth application-default print-access-token
```

instead of `gcloud auth login`.

But if you are using gcloud credentials (not application default) then note that

```
gcloud auth login
```

is an interactive command. You choose user to login as in the browser not on the command line.

You can pre-login before hand and then use credentials you desire. For example:

```
gcloud auth login --account user_A@email.com
gcloud auth login --account user_B@email.com
```

this adds credentials to the credential store (Note that here `--account` is used just for validation making sure webflow chosen account is same as requested here). You can see all available credentials by running

```
gcloud auth list
```

Then you can use specific account on demand

```
gcloud auth print-access-token --account user_A@email.com
gcloud auth print-access-token --account user_B@email.com
```

Note that print-access-token is undocumented command and you should only use it for debugging.

Somewhat more advanced feature is to use configurations

```
gcloud config configurations list
```

You can create new ones by

```
gcloud config configurations create A
gcloud config set account user_A@email.com
gcloud config set project project_A

gcloud config configurations create B
gcloud config set account user_B@email.com
gcloud config set project project_B
```

then you can do

```
gcloud auth print-access-token --configuration A
gcloud auth print-access-token --configuration B
```

the added advantage that not only you can configure account but other attributes like project, compute zone, etc ...

Comment: Thanks!  However I'm looking for how to do this in python.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand you want to make requests to OAuth2.0 protected resources and specify a "caller" account inside your python code.

Here is a nice function I personally use (it has more than what you need as it works differently based on from where it's being called). You simply need to give it the **client ID** of the account you want to be used for the call.

```
def make_iap_request(url, client_id, method='GET', **kwargs):
    """Makes a request to an application protected by Identity-Aware Proxy.

    Args:
      url: The Identity-Aware Proxy-protected URL to fetch.
      client_id: The client ID used by Identity-Aware Proxy.
      method: The request method to use
              ('GET', 'OPTIONS', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE')
      **kwargs: Any of the parameters defined for the request function:
                https://github.com/requests/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py
                If no timeout is provided, it is set to 90 by default.

    Returns:
      The page body, or raises an exception if the page couldn't be retrieved.
    """
    # Set the default timeout, if missing
    if 'timeout' not in kwargs:
        kwargs['timeout'] = 120

    # Figure out what environment we're running in and get some preliminary
    # information about the service account.
    bootstrap_credentials, _ = google.auth.default(
        scopes=[IAM_SCOPE])
    if isinstance(bootstrap_credentials,
                  google.oauth2.credentials.Credentials):
        raise Exception('make_iap_request is only supported for service '
                        'accounts.')
    elif isinstance(bootstrap_credentials,
                    google.auth.app_engine.Credentials):
        requests_toolbelt.adapters.appengine.monkeypatch()

    # For service account's using the Compute Engine metadata service,
    # service_account_email isn't available until refresh is called.
    bootstrap_credentials.refresh(Request())

    signer_email = bootstrap_credentials.service_account_email
    if isinstance(bootstrap_credentials,
                  google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials):
        # Since the Compute Engine metadata service doesn't expose the service
        # account key, we use the IAM signBlob API to sign instead.
        # In order for this to work:
        #
        # 1. Your VM needs the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/iam scope.
        #    You can specify this specific scope when creating a VM
        #    through the API or gcloud. When using Cloud Console,
        #    you'll need to specify the "full access to all Cloud APIs"
        #    scope. A VM's scopes can only be specified at creation time.
        #
        # 2. The VM's default service account needs the "Service Account Actor"
        #    role. This can be found under the "Project" category in Cloud
        #    Console, or roles/iam.serviceAccountActor in gcloud.
        signer = google.auth.iam.Signer(
            Request(), bootstrap_credentials, signer_email)
    else:
        # A Signer object can sign a JWT using the service account's key.
        signer = bootstrap_credentials.signer

    # Construct OAuth 2.0 service account credentials using the signer
    # and email acquired from the bootstrap credentials.
    service_account_credentials = google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials(
        signer, signer_email, token_uri=OAUTH_TOKEN_URI, additional_claims={
            'target_audience': client_id
        })

    # service_account_credentials gives us a JWT signed by the service
    # account. Next, we use that to obtain an OpenID Connect token,
    # which is a JWT signed by Google.
    google_open_id_connect_token = get_google_open_id_connect_token(
        service_account_credentials)

    # Fetch the Identity-Aware Proxy-protected URL, including an
    # Authorization header containing "Bearer " followed by a
    # Google-issued OpenID Connect token for the service account.
    resp = requests.request(
        method, url,
        headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(
            google_open_id_connect_token)}, **kwargs)
    #time.sleep(50)
    if resp.status_code == 403:
        raise Exception('Service account {} does not have permission to '
                        'access the IAP-protected application.'.format(
                            signer_email))
    elif resp.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(
            'Bad response from application: {!r} / {!r} / {!r}'.format(
                resp.status_code, resp.headers, resp.text))
    elif rest.status_code == 500:
        time.sleep(90)
        return 'DONE'
    else:
        return resp.text


def get_google_open_id_connect_token(service_account_credentials):
    """Get an OpenID Connect token issued by Google for the service account.

    This function:

      1. Generates a JWT signed with the service account's private key
         containing a special "target_audience" claim.

      2. Sends it to the OAUTH_TOKEN_URI endpoint. Because the JWT in #1
         has a target_audience claim, that endpoint will respond with
         an OpenID Connect token for the service account -- in other words,
         a JWT signed by *Google*. The aud claim in this JWT will be
         set to the value from the target_audience claim in #1.

    For more information, see
    https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount .
    The HTTP/REST example on that page describes the JWT structure and
    demonstrates how to call the token endpoint. (The example on that page
    shows how to get an OAuth2 access token; this code is using a
    modified version of it to get an OpenID Connect token.)
    """

    service_account_jwt = (
        service_account_credentials._make_authorization_grant_assertion())
    request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    body = {
        'assertion': service_account_jwt,
        'grant_type': google.oauth2._client._JWT_GRANT_TYPE,
    }
    token_response = google.oauth2._client._token_endpoint_request(
        request, OAUTH_TOKEN_URI, body)
    return token_response['id_token']
```

You can read more on other ways [here](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto#iap_make_request-python).