# ERROR TS1086 An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context. get firebaseUiConfig(): NativeFirebaseUIAuthConfig

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Building SPA using Angular/CLI 8.  Running locally until successfully.  Adding firebase auth to app. Got following error message when compiling via VSC:

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/firebaseui-angular/lib/firebaseui-angular-library.component.d.ts:17:9
>   - error TS1086: An accessor cannot be declared in an ambient context.
>
> 17     get firebaseUiConfig(): NativeFirebaseUIAuthConfig;
>              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Ran:  `npm install firebase firebaseui @angular/fire firebaseui-angular --save`

Ran: `ng serve` to complile and view locally and received error.

```
Using: 
typescript ~3.5.3
firebase ^7.13.2
firebaseui ^4.5.0
firebaseui-angular ^4.1.0
angular/cli ~8.3.25
angular/compiler-cli ~8.2.14
angular-devkit/build-angular ~0.803.25
Running on MacPro Catalina v-10.15.3
```

Have looked at other similar posts here on stackoverflow.  Did not find any tied to same circumstances.  Tried some of the solutions that helped others with similar problems but with other circumstances such as angular-animations and flex-layout.  Both cases were lowering versions of each.  Also have tried lowering version of firebaseui from 4.5.0 down to 3.6.0 to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

changing

> firebaseui-angular: ^4.1.0

to

> "firebaseui-angular": "~4.0.1"

in package.json worked for me

Comment: When possible, please make an effort to provide additional explanation instead of just code. Such answers tend to be more useful as they help members of the community and especially new developers better understand the reasoning of the solution, and can help prevent the need to address follow-up questions.

Comment: @Rajan, yes I completely agree with you. In this case, there wasn't any explanation for this error. After searching for a while I found one solution on Github. Before I found the solution, I saw no one has replied to this thread so I thought of doing so after the solution worked for me. Here is another answer that I've given that I've explained in detail - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43218916/python-how-can-i-create-a-googlecredentials-using-a-specific-user-instead-of-ge/60110289#60110289. If you feel I can add some more information, please do let me know, I will edit my answer.